# Accessing objects from json files on disk

Tags: json, database, couchdb, apache-drill

I have ~500 json files on my disk that represents hotels all over the world, each around 30 mbs, all objects have the same structure.

At certain points in my spring server I require to get the information of a single hotel, let's say via `code` (which is inside the json object).

The data is read only, but I might get updates from the hotels providers at certain times, like extra json files or delta changes.

Now I don't want to migrate my json files to a relational database that's for sure, so I've been investigating in the best solution to achieve what I want.

I tried `Apache Drill` because querying straight from json files made me think less headaches of dealing with the data, I did a directory query using Drill, something like:

`SELECT * FROM dfs.'C:\hotels\' WHERE code='1b3474';`

but this obviously does not seem to be the most efficient way for me as it takes around 10 seconds to fetch a single hotel.

At the moment I'm trying out `Couch DB`, but I'm still learning it. Should I migrate all the hotels to a single document (makes a bit of sense to me)? Or should I consider each hotel a document?

I'm just looking for pointers on what is a good solution to achieve what I want, so here to take your opinion.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question, are there any other things you want to know about CouchDB? In general, documents are self-contained, so I would start with each hotel as a document.

Comment: I'm seconding Dominic, each hotel should be stored as a document. Would be more efficient and useful for queries.

Comment: @DominicBarnes I imported the hotels to CouchDB (as is; no changes made to original hotels json structure), document per hotel. What is the proper way to query for a hotel? Should I create a view that does this based on hotel code? Excuse my ignorance and thanks.

Comment: Also, do you reckon that CouchDB is a good solution for my problem? Any other recommendations?

Comment: @prettyvoid you may want to determine what your bottleneck is when you are reading the files. when the process takes 10 seconds to query a hotel, is it because you have slow disk performance or slow what? if you use couch you are moving the problem to another tool, and seems like you are learning couch as you go. fix the bottle neck rather than throw more tech at the problem

Comment: @JohnDaCosta I get your point but at the end I'm trying to achieve the best query time on the same hard disk and system, trying different techniques. Of course when my work is deployed on a real server, things will be even faster. Also, I'm not an expert in either, but CouchDB operates in a different way than Apache Drill and it should be faster after it computes the keys, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @prettyvoid well RAM will always be your fastest option, using any database will essentially provide you with whatever caching/ cache size the db system implements and give you amazing benefits. Pick your poison there. I guess load into any DB that supports a cache size appropriate to your use case...redis / memached are options too.

Comment: if what i am seeing here is right, you may get better results from redis, as couch is using filesystem cache... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314272/couchdb-vs-mongodb-memory-utilization

Comment: @JohnDaCosta Correct memory is faster than disk, however I have lots of data that I can't afford to load all into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that json files do not have indexes associated with them, and Drill does not create indexes for them. So whenever you do a query like `SELECT * FROM dfs.'C:\hotels\' WHERE code='1b3474';` Drill has no choice but to read each json file and parse and process all the data in each file. The more files and data you have, the longer this query will take. If you need to do lookups like this often, I would suggest not using Drill for this use case. Some alternatives are:

- A relational database where you have an index built for the **code** column.
- A key value store where **code** is the key.